# How to make UIScrollview and UITableViewCell in one file

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a template design. and I want to ask:

how do I use the method.
I want the `UIScrollview` at the top left and right.

At the bottom I want to use a `UITableViewCell` and there can be to pull to refresh and load more.

does allow me to use a `UIScrollView` and `UITableViewCell` in one file. is there any reference where I can get such examples.

[image]

Comment: your reputation is now 11

Comment: Do you want the scroll views to be fixed on the screen, or do you want them to scroll off the top when the user scrolls the table view up?

Comment: Hii rob mayoff, i want to For top template make a scrollview maybe With 8 array data. And at the bottom i want to make uitableviewcell maybe 10 array data because i want to make This load More. But If i pull to refresh, data in uiscrollview AND tableviewcell Will be update. May You have a solution or an example?